# Regex split by in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

hello I have a df such as

```
COL1 
NW_011625257.1_0
NW_011623521.1_1
NW_011623521.3_1
NW_011623521.4_1
NW_011623521.1
JZSA01007324.1_2
scaffold_1463_2
scaffold_1463
```

and I would like to cut by the last `'_'` and get

```
COL1              COL2
NW_011625257.1    0
NW_011623521.1    1
NW_011623521.3    1
NW_011623521.4    1
NW_011623521.1    NaN 
JZSA01007324.1    2
scaffold_1463     2
scaffold_1463     NaN
```

So far i tried :

```
df[['COL1','COL2']] = df.COL1.str.split(r'_(?!.*_)', expand=True)
```

instead I get this kind of output:

```
COL1             COL2
NW_011625257.1   0
NW_011623521.1   1
NW_011623521.3   1
NW_011623521.4   1
NW               011623521.1
JZSA01007324.1   2
scaffold_1463    2
scaffold         1463
```

here is an exemple of what I want to select

[image]

Comment: So what is the problem? `NaN`? What do you expect?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew see the last row, it cuts at scaffold_1463  -> scaffold 1463 instead of adding a NaN

Comment: Try `r"(?<=\.\d)_(?!.*_)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it only match the _0 see here https://regex101.com/r/BP3Jnj/1

Comment: `r"_(?=\d$)"` works on this sample. Can you have multiple digits after the `_`? If so, is the determining factor the number of underscores or is the logic related to the `.`?

Comment: Use `r"_(?=\d+$)"`

Comment: Why do you post the same answer twice? Please make this question clear. What exactly do you want to match? `_` that is followed with 1 or more digits at the end of string?

Comment: It does not work since it only select the last one now (see on https://regex101.com/r/BP3Jnj/1)

Comment: The data in the link is different than the one in this post and so the specification seems unclear to me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I only want to match the `_`following any nymber

Comment: *I only want to match the _following any nymber* - no, because if you wanted *that*, you would like to split `scaffold_1463_2` into `['scaffold','1463','2']`. Regex questions must be very clear and precise.

Comment: well no because the only '_' following a number is _2  (the first one is following a letter "d"

Comment: So, you want `r"(?<=\d)_(?=\d+$)"`? A `_` between  a digit on the left, and 1+ digits and end of string on the right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated the post with a picture of what should be selected :)

Comment: And? Does either of my patterns work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no see here https://regexr.com/ in that web side you see direclty the pattern selected (here your pattern only select the last one from ```NW_011627831.1_2```

Comment: I found ! ```(?<=[0-9])_```works

Comment: Come on, you tested at regexr and not in pandas? At regexr, you did not select `m` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
df[['COL1','COL2']] = df.COL1.str.split(r"(?<=\d)_(?=\d+$)", expand=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR0uBP/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<=\d)` - there must a digit right before the current location
- `_` - an underscore
- `(?=\d+$)` - there must be 1+ digits and end of string immediately to the right of the current location.

Pandas test:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['NW_011625257.1_0','NW_011623521.1_1','NW_011623521.3_1','NW_011623521.4_1','NW_011623521.1','JZSA01007324.1_2','scaffold_1463_2','scaffold_1463']})
>>> df[['COL2','COL3']] = df.COL1.str.split(r"(?<=\d)_(?=\d+$)", expand=True)
>>> df
               COL1            COL2  COL3
0  NW_011625257.1_0  NW_011625257.1     0
1  NW_011623521.1_1  NW_011623521.1     1
2  NW_011623521.3_1  NW_011623521.3     1
3  NW_011623521.4_1  NW_011623521.4     1
4    NW_011623521.1  NW_011623521.1  None
5  JZSA01007324.1_2  JZSA01007324.1     2
6   scaffold_1463_2   scaffold_1463     2
7     scaffold_1463   scaffold_1463  None
```